# Plesk - Adding Pear

Tags: php, linux, pear, plesk

I currently have a linux server with Plesk installed. I need to have pear functionality, however I'm having difficulty understanding the documentation.

Viewing phpinfo(), the configure command contains --without-pear.

I have 'edited' my httpd.include file to extend the openbase_dir value to /usr/share/pear and also used this in the include path.

In the pear manual, it states:

```
When using PHP, the PEAR Package Manager is already installed unless one has used the ./configure option --without-pear.
```

Does this mean I need to install the pear package manager again? Do I need to reconfigure PHP with --with-pear? If so how do I do this?

After this step, is there anything else I need to do to enable pear?

Many thanks

Phil

Comment: Plesk means very little - it's just a management system. What's the underlying distro? Ubuntu? Redhat? CentOs? Those would have a php-pear type package available in their repositories.

Comment: Hi Marc, I'm using CentOS. I believe pear has already been installed as I can see a psa-pear directory. However, php's not been configured with it.

Comment: a modular pear wouldn't change the PHP compile options.

Comment: Thanks for the help marc, appriciate your replies. I have managed to get Pear working now :)

Comment: @PhilCross Could you post your answer please so others can see? :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I have just manually installed PEAR with an **apt-get install php-pear** and then I included it in php parameter in each domains and subdomains on my plesk panel. So I added */usr/share/php* (which is PEAR directory, you can get it with **pear config-get php_dir**) in **include_path** and **open_basedir** sections (you can see [here](https://manage.grabweb.net/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=959) how to manage PHP settings on plesk).